# How to server side filtering each field of a table in sequelize (nodejs orm)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, filtering, server-side

I have some trouble to find out how i have to do the filtering part in sequelize ORM.
I already did, server-side pagination and sorting, Following this tutorial for Angular https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

I'am using Sequelize 5.8.5 but not in typescript.

But, in my case, the backend is in nodejs using Sequelize. And i want to do a search of the filter string parameter on each fields of my joined table.
If "string" like field1 OR "string" like field2 OR .... etc

Here is my router.get in sequelize.

```
router.get('', auth.checkToken, function(req, res) {
     let options = {
         include: [{
             model: models.intervention,
             attributes: ['id','start_date','end_date','agent_id','state_id'],
             required: false,
             include: [{
                 model: models.agent,
                 required: false,
             },
             {
                 model: models.state,
                 required: false,
             },
             {
                 model: models.intervention_participation,
                 required: false,
                 include: [{
                     model: models.agent,
                     attributes: ['id','access_token','agent_type_id','firstname','lastname','mail','password'],
                     required: false,
                     include: [{
                         model: models.shift_do,
                         attributes: ['id','shift_id','agent_id','shift_date'],
                         required: false,
                         on: {
                             'agent_id': {
                                 [Op.eq]: Sequelize.col('intervention->agent.id')
                             },
                             'shift_date': {
                                 [Op.eq]: Sequelize.col('intervention.start_date')
                             },
                         },
                         include: [{
                             model: models.shift,
                             required: false,
                         }]
                     }]
                 }]
             },
             {
                 model: models.operating_range_do,
                 required: false,
                 include: [{
                     model: models.operating_range,
                     required: false,
                 }]
             },
             {
                 model: models.equipment_intervention,
                 required: false,
                 include: [{
                     model: models.equipment,
                     required: false,
                     include: [{
                         model: models.equipment_type,
                         required: false,
                         include: [{
                             model: models.work_field,
                             required: false,
                         }]
                 },
                 {
                     model: models.equipment_location,
                     required: false,
                     include: [{
                         model: models.structure,
                         required: false,
                     },
                     {
                         model: models.local,
                         required: false,
                     },
                     {
                         model: models.place,
                         required: false,
                     }]
                 }]
             }]
             },
             {
                 model: models.intervention_helper,
                 required: false,
                 include: [{
                     model: models.external_actor,
                     required: false,
                 }]
             }]
         },
         {
             model: models.work_type,
             required: false
         },
         {
             model: models.di_externe,
             required: false
         }]
     };
     if (req.query.filter) {
         options.where = {
             $or: [
                 { id: { $like: req.query.filter}},
                 { title: { $like: req.query.filter}},
                 { description: { $like: req.query.filter}},
                 { start_date: { $like: req.query.filter}},
             ]
         };
     }
     if (req.query.sort) {
         options.order = [['id', req.query.sort || 'DESC']];
     }
     if (req.query.page && req.query.pageSize) {
         options.offset = req.query.page * req.query.pageSize;
         options.limit = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) + parseInt(req.query.pageSize, 10);
     }
     models.intervention_maincourante
         .findAll(options)
         .then(all => {
             res.send(all);
         });
 });
```

its this part who don't work :

```
if (req.query.filter) {
     options.where = {
         $or: [
             { id: { $like: req.query.filter}},
             { title: { $like: req.query.filter}},
             { description: { $like: req.query.filter}},
             { start_date: { $like: req.query.filter}},
         ]
     };
 }
```

I also tried this way because sometimes the alias for operators didn't works? But it didn't change anything.

```
[Op.or]: [
    { id: { [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%"}},
    { title: { [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%"}},
    { description: { [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%"}},
    { start_date: { [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%"}},
  ]
```

Then i tried :

```
options.where = {
  [Op.or]: [{
    title: {
      [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%",
    },
    description: {
      [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%",
    },
    start_date: {
      [Op.like]: "%" + req.query.filter + "%",
    }
  }]
};
```

What's in the documentation :

```
{
    [Op.or]: [
        {
            title: {
                [Op.like]: 'Boat%'
            }
        },
        {
            description: {
                [Op.like]: '%boat%'
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

Thanks a lot, if someone know how to do it.

Comment: Check what you get in the `req.query.filter` first. Also try to enable logs for query print. It will be helpful.

Comment: I get a simple string, i enabled logs but the query didn't write the logs of this query when filter is set :s I happens when i use bad syntax or sometyhing like that

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested in the comments that query doesn't logs with filter. So assuming there should be any error.

Try to catch the error and log it to identify the issue

```
models.intervention_maincourante
   .findAll(options)
   .then(all => {
        res.send(all);
   }).catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);
   });
```

with the help of this, you will be identifying the exact root cause.

**Update:**

Based on the error, Please check your like clause.

Your like clause should be something like this. Also, make sure you are referring right column names.

```
options.where = {
  [Op.or]: [{
    title: {
      [Op.like]: `%${req.query.filter}%`,
    },
    description: {
      [Op.like]: `%${req.query.filter}%`,
    },
    start_date: {
      [Op.like]: `%${req.query.filter}%`,
    }
  }]
};
```

Comment: Hi, ty for that ! i forgot to add catch :s So it says sqlState: '42S22',
     code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',

Comment: this the filter part FROM `in
tervention_maincourantes` AS `intervention_maincourante` WHERE ((`intervention_maincourante`.`title` LIKE \'GTC%\' AND `interventio
n_maincourante`.`description` LIKE \'GTC%\' AND `intervention_maincourante`.`start_date` LIKE \'GTC%\'))

Comment: How do i do if title == filter OR description == filter ? with your syntax ?

Comment: TY so much i will try

Comment: `%req.query.filter%` OR `%${req.query.filter}%`? I did it with the '${}' structure and it returns the same error :'(

Comment: And a warning saying to stop use string based operators and use instead symbol based.

Comment: Does it prints the query? Also verify the column names are right or not.

Comment: Its good, thanks you so much for helping me, it was about the column name access. I was thinking that the where in the findAll can access to all the fields from the joins but it can't :s. How do i do if I want to filter on each field of each nested includes ?

Comment: I want to make a filter on every string fields of the big join I do here.

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize ORM when you use `$like` operator you can pass the search string directly or wrapped inside `% OR _`. if you want to match some part of the string you can use `$substring` operator.

if your query is a plain string like this 'examplematch' $like operator will look for an exact match.

Refer this doc https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#operators

Comment: Already looked for the doc, I tip the word "GTC" wich is present many times in description field so it may find it. The logs is activated and there is any for this particular query when i set the query.filter parameter. I think, its a syntax problem but i fllowed the right syntax in the doc :s

Answer (score 0):

It's working.

```js
const whereStatement = {}
const { status, startDate, endDate, search } = req.query;

if (status) {
  whereStatement.status = { [Op.eq]: status };
}
if (startDate && endDate) {
  whereStatement.createdAt = { [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate] }
}
if (search) {
  whereStatement.username = { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` }
}

let Datefilter = "";

if (startDate && endDate) {
  Datefilter =
    startDate && endDate ? {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: moment(startDate).startOf("day").toDate(),
        $lte: moment(endDate).endOf("day").toDate(),
      },
    } : {};
  console.log("startDateto", Datefilter);
} else if (startDate) {
  console.log("startDate");
  Datefilter = startDate
    ? {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: moment(startDate).startOf("day").toDate(),
        $lte: moment(new Date()).endOf("day").toDate(),
      },
    } : {};
}
feedback = await feedbackModel.paginate({
  where: whereStatement,
  Datefilter
});
```